# Implementing multiprocessing to deal with heavy input/output on HPC

Tags: python, numpy, input, multiprocessing, processing-efficiency

I need to process over 10 million spectroscopic data sets. The data is structured like this: there are around 1000 .fits (.fits is some data storage format) files, each file contains around 600-1000 spectra in which there are around 4500 elements in each spectra (so each file returns a ~1000*4500 matrix). That means each spectra is going to be repeatedly read around 10 times (or each file is going to be repeatedly read around 10,000 times) if I am going to loop over the 10 million entries. Although the same spectra is repeatedly read around 10 times, it is not duplicate because each time I extract different segments of the same spectra. With the help of @Paul Panzer, I already avoid reading the same file multiple times.

I have a catalog file which contains all the information I need, like the coordinates `x`, `y`, the radius `r`, the strength `s`, etc. The catalog also contains the information to target which file I am going to read (identified by `n1`, `n2`) and which spectra in that file I am going to use (identified by `n3`).

The code I have now is:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip
import itertools
import fitsio

x = []
y = []
r = []
s = []
n1 = []
n2 = []
n3 = []
with open('spectra_ID.dat') as file_ID, open('catalog.txt') as file_c:
    for line1, line2 in izip(file_ID,file_c):
        parts1 = line1.split()
        parts2 = line2.split()
        n1.append(int(parts1[0]))
        n2.append(int(parts1[1]))
        n3.append(int(parts1[2]))
        x.append(float(parts2[0]))         
        y.append(float(parts2[1]))        
        r.append(float(parts2[2]))
        s.append(float(parts2[3]))  

def data_analysis(n_galaxies):
    n_num = 0
    data = np.zeros((n_galaxies), dtype=[('spec','f4',(200)),('x','f8'),('y','f8'),('r','f8'),('s','f8')])

    idx = np.lexsort((n3,n2,n1))
    for kk,gg in itertools.groupby(zip(idx, n1[idx], n2[idx]), lambda x: x[1:]):
        filename = "../../data/" + str(kk[0]) + "/spPlate-" + str(kk[0]) + "-" + str(kk[1]) + ".fits"
        fits_spectra = fitsio.FITS(filename)
        fluxx = fits_spectra[0].read()
        n_element = fluxx.shape[1]
        hdu = fits_spectra[0].read_header()
        wave_start = hdu['CRVAL1']
        logwave = wave_start + 0.0001 * np.arange(n_element)
        wavegrid = np.power(10,logwave)

        for ss, plate1, mjd1 in gg:
            if n_num % 1000000 == 0:
                print n_num
            n3new = n3[ss]-1
            flux = fluxx[n3new]
            ### following is my data reduction of individual spectra, I will skip here
            ### After all my analysis, I have the data storage as below:
            data['spec'][n_num] = flux_intplt
            data['x'][n_num] = x[ss]
            data['y'][n_num] = y[ss]
            data['r'][n_num] = r[ss]
            data['s'][n_num] = s[ss]

            n_num += 1

    print n_num
    data_output = FITS('./analyzedDATA/data_ALL.fits','rw')
    data_output.write(data)
```

I kind of understand that the multiprocessing need to remove one loop, but pass the index to the function. However, there are two loops in my function and those two are highly correlated, so I do not know how to approach. Since the most time-consuming part of this code is reading files from disk, so the multiprocessing need to take full advantage of cores to read multiple files at one time. Could any one shed a light on me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of `global vars`, you can't use `global vars` with `processes`
2. Merge your multiple `global vars` into **one** container class or dict,
   assigning different segments of the same spectra into one data set
3. Move your `global with open(...` into a `def ...`
4. Separate `data_output` into a own `def ...`
5. Try **first**, without `multiprocessing`, this concept:

   ```
   for line1, line2 in izip(file_ID,file_c):
       data_set = create data set from (line1, line2)
       result = data_analysis(data_set)
       data_output.write(data)
   ```
6. Consider to use 2 `processes` one for **file reading** and one for **file writing**.
   Use `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n)` for `data_analysis`.
   Communicate between `processes` using `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()`

Comment: Would you write down the code you though? I could not understand it clearly.

Comment: Start with Point 2. an 3., edit the code in your Question accordingly.